# I keep getting Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' as snapshot data when listening to my Stream.periodic

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to listen to a async function which make a request to an API using Stream.periodic, the expected result is that i get the request response body on my Stream to use with my StreamBuilder, except that i keep getting

```dart
Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
```

every time the periodic stream runs.

Here's the code i'm using to do this:

```dart
get systemLoad async {
    return '0';
    // Actual call to be used whenever this problem is solved
    // return await _fetch('systemloadavg');
}
```

```dart
Stream _systemLoad = Stream.periodic(
    Duration(seconds: 10),
    (_) => service.systemLoad
).startWith( service.systemLoad );
```

```dart
StreamBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
      if ( snap.hasError ) return Container();
      
      // prints: ConnectionState.active
      print(snap.connectionState.toString());
      // prints: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
      print(snap.data.toString());

      return Container();
    },
    stream: _systemLoad
);
```

Comment: You're trying to read a value of an `Async` function without awaiting for it to complete which is why it says `instance of Future<dynamic>`. You've to use `await` keyword before calling the function, like `await service.systemload`, this means you're waiting to let the `async` function finish its operation and then only reading it, not before.

Comment: If i added await to the periodic contructor or to the startsWith from rxdart it was throwning an error, i found another solution, that i'm going to add to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using asyncMap on the Stream right after startsWith.

The result was:

```dart
Stream _systemLoad = Stream.periodic(
    Duration(seconds: 10),
    (_) => service.systemLoad
).startWith( service.systemLoad ).asyncMap((event) async => await event);
```

This solved the problem and did not throw any errors or warnings.